# screen is not updated after purchasing an item using in app purchase android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing in-App purchase feature in android App. When user click on the item, it shows price of that item on Google Play. After purchasing the item, it will not update the screen(removing buy image on that item and updating the screen). This is my the code:

```
private static boolean buyUfo = false;
private static final String BUYUFO ="buyUfo";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreference; 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    sharedPreference = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreference.edit();
    buyUfo = sharedPreference.getBoolean(BUYUFO, false);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log_Billing("InAppBilling", "get purchased items from service  result = " + result);
        if (mInappBillingHelper == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log_Billing("InAppBilling", "get purchased items from service failed !!!!");
            return;
        }

        boolean hasItemBoughtdiscovered = false;
        Purchase ufoPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(getString(R.string.SKU_Ufo));
        if ((ufoPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(ufoPurchase))) {
            Log_Billing("InAppBilling", "User has bought UFO alreadly" + ufoPurchase);
            editor.putBoolean(BUYUFO, true);
            hasItemBoughtdiscovered = true;
            editor.commit();
            if(hasItemBoughtdiscovered) {
                updateSettingUi();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to make **buyUfo** to be true after purchase. My question is that After InApp Purchase, Is QueryInventoryFinishedListener Called or not?. If not then which Listener is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onResume() of your activity get value from shared preference, check is it true or false if true i.e. purchased changed ui(icons) in your activity

Comment: You mean like this:                                                                       @Override
 protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 buyTheme = sharedPreference.getBoolean(BUYTHEME, false);
  
 }

Comment: yes.and by checking value you may change screen.I have done this.working for me.

Comment: Can you explain me the procedure that after purchasing an item, what happen?

Comment: If in-app purchase done you are storing boolean value in shared preference just check it again & change your ui according to your shared preference value.in oncreate & onResume

Comment: May you share your in app code with me?. Specially after purchase Listener code.Thanks for your help man

Comment: actually your are doing in correct way.just before iff(hasItemBoughtdiscovered) {updateSettingUi();} condition get updated value for hasItemBoughtdiscovered from shared preference.your trying to check value which your have got before in-app

Comment: No..its not working.It didn't remove the image or make screen working